# Magic code while OAuth using Botframework. Any way around?

Tags: node.js, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, botframework

While logging into the bot, using Botframework OAuthPrompt function, user is required to log in on Microsoft page and then asked to copy magic code and paste it in the conversation with bot. Is there a way to automatically pass it without user input ?

Docs says that it should be solved in v4 but in both emulator and my mobile app it is still required.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv1%2Ccsharp%2Cbot-oauth

I would like to make log in process easier for my users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been improvements to the channels to support new authentication features, such as new WebChat and DirectLineJS libraries to eliminate the need for the 6-digit magic code verification. You can follow these links to prevent the magic code from showing up:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4632#issuecomment-441957719( refer to @compulim's comment here, who is the developer of Web Chat and has specified the steps to eliminate the magic code flow).
- https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/pull/1218( pull request for the token server sample).

Also, note that if your browser is set to block 3rd party cookies, it will fallback to magic code flow.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For your bot emulator, you can disable this from your bot settings. 
Go to bot emulator settings and uncheck the "use sign-in verification code .." option.