# Bot Authentication with MS Graph -how to dynamically read 6 digit code with out manual type in

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework, chatbot

I am able to authenticate my chat bot users with Azure AD and MSGraph, but it is showing up a 6 digit code on my screen. How can I avoid this step.I would like my users to be able to login once they enter their user name, password and 'Log in'.But instead it is showing up a 6 digit code on another window and the user need reply with this number to be able to successfully login.

How can I make my bot dynamically read this code without additional user input.
Is this behavior only with Bot emulator ?

*Note:*
I did not tested this with MS teams and other channels.Is it going to behave the same with MS teams and other channels as well?

**Update**

I can disable magic code from my bot emulator settings by unchecking the "use sign-in verification code .." option.

But in other channels, still my bot users need to enter this 6 digit code.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magic code while OAuth using Botframework. Any way around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57053009/magic-code-while-oauth-using-botframework-any-way-around)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [OauthCards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-oauth-card) for authentication in MS Teams.

WebChat and DirectLineJS libraries have had improvements to support new authentication features like eliminate the need for the 6-digit magic code verification. You can refer to these links to prevent the magic code from showing up:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4632#issuecomment-441957719( refer to @compulim's comment here, who is the developer of Web Chat and has specified the steps to eliminate the magic code flow).
- https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/pull/1218( pull request for the token server sample).
- Additionally, https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1001#issuecomment-434530463 is a solution which involves webchat which works with AAD and no magic code.

Note: If your browser is set to block 3rd party cookies, it will again fall back to the magic code flow.

Hope this helps